# Adding multiple values inside while loop

Tags: php

As an example I have four input text boxes in a form.  I am trying to calculate the cost of each item type (`quantity` * `cost`) and the compute a total of all items. I have placed the formula inside a while loop to calculate cost of all the possible items found in the form. I am not receiving any result in return for the total cost? [Demo](http://holaweblearning.co.nf/php_learning/test3.php)

php

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
      $discount = $_POST['discount'];
      $i = 1;
      while(isset($_POST['quantity'.$i])){
          $quantity = $_POST['quantity'.$i];
          $cost = $_POST['cost'.$i];
          $total = $quantity * $cost;
          $i++;
      }

}
```

html

```
<div id="contact-area">
  <form action="" method="post">
    <label>Quantity:</label> <input type="text" name="quantity1" id="quantity1"> <label>Cost:</label><input type="text" name="cost1" id="cost1"><br /><br />
    <label>Quantity:</label> <input type="text" name="quantity2" id="quantity2"> <label>Cost:</label><input type="text" name="cost2" id="cost2"><br /><br />
  <br /><br />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" >
  </form>

<?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
  echo"<p>Amount Due: $". $total ."</p>";
}
?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're re-assigning `$total` instead of adding to it, so the final total will just be from the last item. It should be:

```
$total += $quantity * $cost;
       ^
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `$total` variable is being over-written every loop.

It should be:

```
$total += ($quantity * $cost);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add

```
$total = 0;
```

before while loop and in loop change

```
$total = $quantity * $cost;
```

to

```
$total += $quantity * $cost;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
  $discount = $_POST['discount'];
  $i = 1;
  $total = 0;
  while(isset($_POST['quantity'.$i])){
      $quantity = $_POST['quantity'.$i];
      $cost = $_POST['cost'.$i];
      $total += $quantity * $cost;
      $i++;
  }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Rewriting your code like this will resolve the issue:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
      $discount = $_POST['discount'];
      $i = 1;
      $total = 0;
      while(isset($_POST['quantity'.$i])){
          $total += $_POST['quantity'.$i] * $_POST['cost'.$i];
          $i++;
      }

}
```

This is what was changed:

- Adding a `$total = 0;` before the `while` loop to ensure that variable is assigned no matter what.
- Removing the `$quantity = $_POST['quantity'.$i];` & `$cost = $_POST['cost'.$i];` since those are superfluous duplications of values that can be accessed directly.
- Changing `$total =` to `$total +=` so the `$total` is actually accumulated in the variable.